# Package calling functions from importing program

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package, python-import

Can a package call a function inside of the file that is importing it?

For example:

Code of file1.py

```
import file2

def onstart():
    print('Hello World!')
```

Code of file2.py

```
# ... something
onstart()
```

Then if I run file1, I want the output to be

> Hello World!

I tried just calling it in file2.py, but that gave an error

*`NameError: name 'onstart' is not defined`*

Comment: No, I don't believe so.

Comment: Not really possible, and also redundant. Just define all the functions in the same file.

Comment: I was trying to make something like ursina. If you make a function update() and import ursina, it will be called every frame. Do you know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way.
If I import __main__ in file2 and make a class in file2, if I call that class in file1, I can run functions from file1.

In file1

```
import file2

test = file2.Test()

def onstart():
    print('Hello World!')

test.run()
```

In file2

```
import __main__

class Test:
    def run(self):
        if hasattr(__main__,'onstart') and __main__.onstart:
            __main__.onstart()
```

Output

> Hello World!

I found this answer by searching in Ursina's source code.

Answer (score 0):

if you put this in file2

```
from file1 import *

onstart()
```

and run file1 it should output

> Hello World!

you could add this to the end if the file closes instantly for you

```
input("Press Enter to continue.")
```

Comment: Please test your code before you post them as answers

Comment: This only works if file1 doesn't reference anything from file2, because if it does, python spits out an AttributeError due to a circular import.
So since I do need to reference variables and functions from file2 in file1, this is not possible